# Why is my Code not executing beyond this point

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am playing around with php but the script doesnt execute to the last point and with no error...

What i am trying to do is checking the input of the user and comparing it what is in db and then applying conditions. So i have 2 files. **update.php** and **dash.php**.

**dash.php** is my html form page and i included 'update.php' in it

In my **update.php**, i have these codes

me.php is my html form page and i included 'update.php' in it

In my update.php, i have these codes

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once('database.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $q = $_GET['q'];

    $next = $q + 1;

    if($q == 26)
    {
        echo '<h2>Weldone!!</h2>';
    }
    elseif($q <= 25){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Email=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', 
                          $_SESSION['login']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $Mark = $row['Mark'];
        $Correct = $Mark + 1;
        $Fail = $Mark + 0;

        $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE qid = ?";
        $stmtb = $conn->prepare($sqlb); 
        $stmtb->bind_param('s', $q);
        $stmtb->execute();
        $resultb = $stmtb->get_result();

        $rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc();

        $Answer = 
            $rowb['Answer'];

        $Pick = $_POST['ans'];

        if($Pick ==  $Answer)
        {
            $sqld = "UPDATE Students SET Mark=? WHERE Email = ?";
            $stmtd = $conn->prepare($sqld); 
            $stmtd->bind_param('ss', $Correct,$_SESSION['login']);
            $stmtd->execute();
            $resultd = $stmtd->get_result();  
            echo "correct" ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='dash.php?q='.$next.';</script>";
    }
}//post submit
?>
```

The else statement doesnt run. so it keeps reloading the same page.

Also i want to ask why i keep getting the value of 2 for my $Correct variable stored on the database into column Mark for a single correct question instead of 1. What could be wrong?

Lastly, i dont want the script to run if the browser is edited by the user by changing the value of $q from the browser, because i am using get method, is there a way to do that.

Please be nice with your comments. Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: You're adding `1` to `$Mark` to get `$Correct`. So if `$Mark == 1`, `$Correct == 2`.

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to change a value, don't get it from the browser. Save it in a session variable.

Comment: `$Fail = $Mark + 0;` What's the point of adding 0? What is the logic that sets `Correct = Mark + 1` and `Fail = Mark`?

Comment: Tanx sire!!!! Am a newbie!! Pardon my mistakes...

Comment: But  wait!!! The $Mark is 0 in the database. 0 +1 So $Correct should be 1

Comment: This echoing `<script>` tags is ugly. I dont understand why i am seeing this more and more.

Comment: Dont be offended!!! Does that solve the issue on ground @GetSet